# What is the role of Client Application in this example? Is it redundant? Azure APIM, AAD

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-api-management

What is the role of the Client application in this example below?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad

An access token can be requested via Developer Portal without the steps related to the Client application on the link above. In other words, it works after the client app is removed and settings point to the backend app.

Any idea?

Comment: *Register another application (client-app) in Azure AD to represent a client application that needs to call the API.*, Seems pretty clear to me unless you mean another application.

Comment: It works after the client app is removed and settings point to the backend app

Answer (score 0):

The client app calls the API and calls the back-end app. It's an extra layer of security to avoid unauthorized access. To get a valid OAUth token, every client application that calls the API needs to be registered as an application in Azure AD.

Comment: Do you know about this? It works after the client app is removed and settings point to the backend app.

Answer (score 0):

In that particular tutorial client app is used in APIM dev portal. When users navigate to dev portal and want to make a call to AAD protected API they need to supply token along with request. Having client app created for dev portal simplifies this flow as portal can request token for user.